# Permission denied when trying to run C program in terminal

Tags: c, macos, cs50

I'm completely new to programming. I'm actually learning from a Harvard class on iTunes U. When trying to code along side the instructor I've ran into a problem. I can't run my .c program in terminal. I've tried the sudo commands, and I've searched with Google and I can't seem to find an answer, probably because I'm so new to programming. It's probably something I've overlooked or I just don't understand yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    printf("temperature in f: ");
    float f = GetFloat();
    float c=f / 9.0 * (f-32);

    Printf("%. if F = %. if c\n", f, c)
```

I'm using Sublime text editor on a MacBook with Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.x).

Comment: This code is incomplete and has several errors in. Is this all, and how do you try to run it?

Comment: i actually redid my code, added a library i was missing for the code. but now I'm getting an "undefined symbols for architecture" error. ill update it with the redone code. also i use terminal to run them.

Comment: In future, please do not edit the question so as to invalidate answers already given.  If you wish to update the question with a new, revised version, that's fine — as long as you leave the original alone so that the answers remain relevant.  Note that the `return 0;` is preferred, but both C99 and C11 allow you to leave it out (sadly; it was not one of the better moves on the part of the standards committee, in my view, though there were complex reasons why it was felt to be necessary — related to 'the C++ committee decided to do it first', and I don't understand why they did it).

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler should have warn you about some errors:

```
// string.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) // There must be a return statement
{
    printf("temperature in f: ");
    float f = GetFloat();
    float c = f / 9.0 * (f-32);
    printf("%f if F = %f if c\n", f, c); // Missing ';' is the most common syntax error
    return 0; // Here is the return
} // Do not forget to close your brackets
```

When you do:

> gcc string.c -o myprogram

It will tell you what is wrong in your program. Once you have fixed all the errors you can run the program with:

> ./myprogram

Understand that you cannot **run** a C-file: the `.c` contains human-readable instructions for the machine. You have to compile it, i.e. translate it into a language that your computer will understand : it is roughly your compiled `myprogram` (and you do not want to open it to look what it contains, it will burn your eyes :p).

Comment: Thank you! it turned out i had a lot to do. this was all kinds of messed up. i still have a ton of stuff to learn still.

Comment: Yes, it seems so ;) Have a look at the [C tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) : you will find plenty of good references to learn and master C-language !

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the below answer your compiler should throw the below error also:

```
undefined reference to `Printf'
```

check case of your printf()